# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to Recensione

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a problem that many people had but i don't understand how can i get out of it. Please help me in my case and do not mark as duplicated. I have a recyclerview linked with firebase in a fragment.
I have to retrieve all the items behind the "recensione".
All the items have got some textviews inside where it is written some strings from the database. But when i try to retrieve the items in the database i get the error:

> ```
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.ji.architettiadvisor.Data.Recensione
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.ji.architettiadvisor.DisplayStudio$PlaceholderFragment.getUpdates(DisplayStudio.java:337)
>                                                                              at com.ji.architettiadvisor.DisplayStudio$PlaceholderFragment.access$000(DisplayStudio.java:233)
>                                                                              at com.ji.architettiadvisor.DisplayStudio$PlaceholderFragment$1.onChildAdded(DisplayStudio.java:358)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblz.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
> ```

Here is my Recensione.class:

```
public class Recensione {
private String Commento;
private String Rating;
private String Username;
private String Data;

public String getData() {
    return Data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    Data = data;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    Username = username;
}

public String getRating() {
    return Rating;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    Rating = rating;
}


public String getCommento() {
    return Commento;
}

public void setCommento(String commento) {
    Commento = commento;
}}
```

Here my PlaceholderFragment / DisplayStudio.class:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap googleMapa;

    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static DisplayStudio.PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        DisplayStudio.PlaceholderFragment fragment = new DisplayStudio.PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    RecyclerView rv;
    MyCommentsAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Recensione> recensioni = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bl = getArguments();
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1)
        {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profilo, container, false);

            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

            String desc = intent.getStringExtra("Desc");
            final String names = intent.getStringExtra("Nome");

            TextView test = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
            TextView descr = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            TextView key = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.key);

            test.setText(names);
            descr.setText(desc);

            String MyKey = bl.getString(MY_STUDIO_KEY);
            key.setText(MyKey);

        return rootView;
        }
        else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2)
        {


            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            final String names = intent.getStringExtra("Nome");

            //INITIALIZE FIREBASE
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Studi").child(names).child("valutazioni").child("recensioni");
            mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
            /* Ricarica tutte le opinioni */
            refreshData();
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_opinioni, container, false);
            rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MyRecView2s);

            Recensione rc = new Recensione();
            rc.setUsername("Luca");
            rc.setCommento("Non male, da app");
            rc.setRating("10");
            rc.setData("oggi");
            //ci vuole il push prima del setvalue
            mDatabase.child(names).setValue(rc);
            rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

            return rootView;
        }
        else
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map , mapFragment).commit();
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


            if (mapFragment == null) {
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map , mapFragment).commit();
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }


            return rootView;
        }
    }
    private void getUpdates(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

        recensioni.clear();

        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Recensione s=new Recensione();
            s.setUsername(ds.getValue(Recensione.class).getUsername());
            s.setCommento(ds.getValue(Recensione.class).getCommento());
            s.setRating(ds.getValue(Recensione.class).getRating());
            s.setData(ds.getValue(Recensione.class).getData());
            recensioni.add(s);
        }

        if(recensioni.size()>0){
            adapter=new MyCommentsAdapter(getActivity(), recensioni);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"NON CI SONO ANCORA OPINIONI.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    //RETRIEVE
    private void refreshData(){

        mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                getUpdates(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                getUpdates(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMapa = googleMap;
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

        final String names = intent.getStringExtra("Nome");

        String posizione1 = intent.getStringExtra("Posizione1");
        String posizione2 = intent.getStringExtra("Posizione2");

        try
        {
            //Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,posizione1 + " " + posizione2 , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   //not a double
            Double protein = Double.parseDouble(posizione1);
            Double protein2 = Double.parseDouble(posizione2);
             LatLng sydney = new LatLng(protein,protein2);                                                                           //custom icon in drawable
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(names)/*.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.cast_abc_scrubber_control_off_mtrl_alpha))*/);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 12.0f));

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            //  Toast.makeText(DisplayStudio.this, e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   //not a double
        }



    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return DisplayStudio.PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "PROFILO";
            case 1:
                return "OPINIONI";
            case 2:
                return "MAPS";
        }
        return null;
    }
}}
```

Everything is at the bottom of this activity.
Every different "recensione" has its custom pubblished id that does not matter...

[image: What i need to retrieve]

How can i fix it? I have really no idea and i do not understand what is wrong, and sorry but i am new at this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very inefficient debugger. Please reduce the code to the [minimum code needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please). The problem likely has nothing to do with your activity, maps, clicks or views, but purely depends on where you attach your `ChildEventListener` and the JSON data at that location. By reducing your code to just the part needed to reproduce the problem, you'll make it easier to help you and thus are more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of the method `Datasnapshot.getValue()` is the class you want to cast your value to. You're probably trying to cast it to `String`. Change your `getUpdates` method to look like this:

```
private void getUpdates(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    recensioni.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Recensione s=new Recensione();
        s.setUsername(ds.getValue(String.class));
        s.setCommento(ds.getValue(String.class));
        s.setRating(ds.getValue(String.class));
        s.setData(ds.getValue(String.class));
        recensioni.add(s);
    }

    if(recensioni.size()>0){
        adapter=new MyCommentsAdapter(getActivity(), recensioni);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"NON CI SONO ANCORA OPINIONI.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```